# Problem related to Connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know and have proved them following theorem:

Let $G$  be a 2-connected graph. Then for any 2 distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ , there exist $2$ Internally disjoint $(x-y)$-paths.

I changed the statement a little:

‘Let $G$  be a connected graph. Suppose $G$ has no bridge. Show that for any 2 distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ , there exist $2$ edge-disjoint $(x-y)$-paths. ’

I want to prove or disprove this but was not able to do it. It seems correct(I created many examples that agrees with it) but I am not certain.

I tried mathematical induction(on the distance between $x$ and $y$) and method by contradiction.

Comment: this is a special case of Manger's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem

Comment: @Fuseques That is an answer not a comment, please write it up as such.

Answer (score 1):

what you are referring to is a special case of Manger's theorem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem